# Cannot find option to turn sandbox mode off for facebook tab app

Tags: facebook, sandbox, mode

I have just created a facebook tab application and everything works fine. However I can't turn off the Sandbox mode to make it live to non admins. I have looked in Settings - Advanced but there is no sign off it. Have I missed something? is there more info I need to supply?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs valid contact email to be added in settings.
and in status&review in top of the window there is sandbox mode turn on/off